# SOAP request in R

Tags: r, soap, rcurl, httr

Does anyone know how to formulate following SOAP request with R?

```
POST /API/v201010/AdvertiserService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: advertising.criteo.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "https://advertising.criteo.com/API/v201010/clientLogin"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <clientLogin xmlns="https://advertising.criteo.com/API/v201010">
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
      <source>string</source>
    </clientLogin>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: What have your current efforts thus far obtained?

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I found the solution in the [documentation of the RCurl package](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/RCurlJSS.pdf).

Comment: Great. Remember to mark your answer as accepted by clicking the checkbox to the left of the answer, so that others can see your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This solves the problem:

```
library(RCurl)

headerFields =
  c(Accept = "text/xml",
    Accept = "multipart/*",
    'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    SOAPAction = "https://advertising.criteo.com/API/v201010/clientLogin")

body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
  <clientLogin xmlns="https://advertising.criteo.com/API/v201010">
  <username>string</username>
  <password>string</password>
  <source>string</source>
  </clientLogin>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>'

curlPerform(url = "https://advertising.criteo.com/API/v201010/AdvertiserService.asmx",
                          httpheader = headerFields,
                          postfields = body
                          )
```

Comment: How would this look if you needed to include an SSL certificate and password?