# SSOAP processWSDL SoapType

Tags: r, soap

I'm new to R/web services.

I'm trying to use R's SSOAP package to get/post soap messages.

I want to generate functions definitions using the genSOAPCLientInterface by way of the processWSDL function.

when i run the processWSDL function, i get the following error message, which i dont know how to interpret:

Error in SOAPType(el, namespaceDefs=namespaceDefinitions):could not find function "SOAPType"

any help/pointers would be very helpful.

```
wsdl_doc<-xmlParse(paste0(wsdl_url, '?wsdl')
definitions<-processWSDL(wsdl_doc, verbose=T, useInternalNodes=T)

Error in SOAPType(el, namespaceDefs = namespaceDefinitions) :
could not find function "SOAPType"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOAPType is a class used in SSOAP package, but it is declared in package XMLSchema. And for some reason it is not an exported class.

This workaround helped me to make the function processWSDL() working for me:

```
SOAPType = XMLSchema:::SOAPType
def <- processWSDL(doc)
```

Comment: thanks so much kirill. But i'm running into what i think is a similar issue with the genSOAPCLientInterface() call.

    Error in .setupMethodsTable(def=initialize=True):
    no slot of name "group" for this object of class "derivedDefaultMethod"

can you give any guidance? thanks again.

Comment: Not sure I can help you more with SSOAP. I also had problems with genSOAPClientInterface. In my case it was infinite recursion. I can offer you using [SOAP UI](https://www.soapui.org/) in combination with [RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717706/soap-request-in-r)